# How to reverse a number using PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a PLSQL code to revers the number

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE 
   v_num number :=120;
   v_store_values NUMBER;
   v_length NUMBER;
   v_output NUMBER; 
BEGIN
   SELECT LENGTH(v_num) INTO v_length FROM DUAL;
   FOR v_counter IN 1..v_length LOOP
         SELECT SUBSTR(v_num,-(v_counter),v_counter) INTO v_store_values FROM DUAL;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_store_values);  
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**It gives me the output :**

```
0
2
1
```

But I want the output on horizontal : `021`

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need PL/SQL; consider

```
SQL> select listagg(substr('120', -level, 1)) result
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= length('120');

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
021

SQL>
```

---

If it *has to be* PL/SQL:

```
SQL> declare
  2    result varchar2(20);
  3  begin
  4    select listagg(substr('120', -level, 1)) result
  5    into result
  6    from dual
  7    connect by level <= length('120');
  8
  9    dbms_output.put_line(result);
 10  end;
 11  /
021

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple `REVERSE` function below but Please note it is an undocumented feature.

```
select reverse(to_char(120))
from   dual;
```

OR  you can use the supported `utl_raw.reverse`

```
 select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_raw.reverse(utl_raw.cast_to_raw (to_char(120))))
 from   dual;
```